# Displaying different symbols depending on the menu tier

Tags: jquery

I'm using the code below to insert a bullet point and a minus sign on certain levels of a menu.

It works to a degree. I want level 2 items to show a bullet, level 3 items to show a minus.

At the moment that only works if a page has subpages - if it doesn't have subpages then it doesn't show the bullet point.

My question is - How can I include pages without subpages to show a bullet?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('ul.children').has('ul').children('li').children('a').prepend('&#8226; '); //Bullets on level 2
        $('ul.children ul.children').children('li').children('a').prepend('&#45; '); //Dashes on level 3
    });
});
```

Comment: rather than using `children().children()` you can use http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use the `.not()` function

```
$('ul li ul li').not('ul li ul li ul li').prepend('&#8226; '); //second level, but not third
$('ul li ul li ul li').prepend('&#45;'); //third level
```